# Do something in another class when the locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization method called

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-location

In the following code, I have a `LocationManager` class which provides the city name of the current location via the `@Published` property wrapper `lastSearchedCity`.

Then I have a `SearchManagerViewModel` class that should be in charge of presenting the city name on `SwiftUI` views based on some conditions (not currently shown in the code below) via the `@Published` property wrapper `cityName`. It properly shows the city name when I call the `searchAndSetCity()` method from `ContentView.swift` inside an `onAppear` modifier.

My issue is that if the user turned `Location Services` off and turns it back On while he/she is in the `ContentView.swift` the `Text` view doesn't update, which is understandable since the `searchAndSetCity()` method would need to be called again.

***How can I call the `searchAndSetCity()` method located inside the `SearchManagerViewModel` class every time the `locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager)` method is called?*** I believed this method is called every time the authorization status changes.

### LocationManager Class

```
final class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    @Published var lastSearchedCity = ""
        
    var hasFoundOnePlacemark:Bool = false

    func checkIfLocationServicesIsEnabled(){
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
                self.locationManager.delegate = self
                self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest/// kCLLocationAccuracyBest is the default
                self.checkLocationAuthorization()
            }else{
                // show message: Services desabled!
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func checkLocationAuthorization(){
        switch locationManager.authorizationStatus{
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            // show message
        case .denied:
            // show message
        case .authorizedWhenInUse, .authorizedAlways:
            /// app is authorized
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        checkLocationAuthorization()
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        hasFoundOnePlacemark = false
        
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)-> Void in
            if error != nil {
                self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
                // show error message
            } 
            if placemarks!.count > 0 {
                if !self.hasFoundOnePlacemark{
                    self.hasFoundOnePlacemark = true
                    let placemark = placemarks![0]
                    
                    self.lastSearchedCity = placemark.locality ?? ""               
                }
                self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            }else{
                // no places found
            }
        })
    }
}
```

### SearchManagerViewModel Class

```
class SearchManagerViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var cityName = "" // use this directly in SwifUI views
    
    @ObservedObject private var locationManager = LocationManager()
    
    // Call this directly fron onAppear in SwiftUI views
    // This method is more complex than what is shown here. It handles other things like HTTP requests etc.
    func searchAndSetCity(){
        locationManager.checkIfLocationServicesIsEnabled()
        self.cityName = locationManager.lastSearchedCity
    }
}
```

### ContentView.swift

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject private var searchManager = SearchManagerViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(searchManager.cityName)
                .font(.callout)
        }
        .onAppear{
            searchManager.searchAndSetCity()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's best to do the authorization and location updates in different View structs, each with their own @StateObjects containing their own location managers.

Comment: Hmm, would you mind elaborating a little more on the code structure?